# HTML, CSS: Resizing the IMG with transitioning while resizing

Tags: html, css, image, resize, transition

I've got this code...

```
<img class="logo" src="img/logo.jpg"> <!-- Logo size is 96x96 -->
```

...and this

```
.logo {
    transition: .5s;
}

.logo:hover {
    transition: .5s;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
}
```

It resizes on hovering, but not with transitioning. I just hover it and it instantly resizes, and I have no idea why does `transition` not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to define the same transition property for the image and the hover pseudoclass. If you don't define `transition` in `.logo:hover`, it will take the previously set value of half a second.

The problem here is that you must specify an initial width and height for the image in order to have it resize smoothly.

Comment: Yeah I know, I added the second `transition` just in case because it didn't work. What do you mean with "specify an initial width and height"?

Comment: In `.logo` you neither set a width nor height. You should do that to make the image transition work.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong with the CSS causing it not to transition.

First, as @WaisKamal said, you need to set initial states to transition from. Images size automatically in HTML but that's not a valid starting point for CSS.

Second, you need to define WHAT properties are being transitioned.

So you would need to add width and height. Or you can use the `all` identifier:

```
.logo {
   display:block; //make sure the image is a block element
   width: 96px;
   height: 96px;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.logo:hover {
   width: 128px;
   height: 128px;
}
```

Now that will work but it's going to be kind of janky since animating height/width cause page repaints.

**Instead, I would suggest using a `transform` on the image.**

```
.logo {
       display:block; //make sure the image is a block element
       // initial size is fine here because we're using a transform
       transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .logo:hover {
       transform: scale(2) // decimal notation 2 = 200% = 128x128px
    }
```

Comment: Well, I've never set anything except `.5s` in transition and everything worked fine. The only thing I had to fix is to set the initial size

Comment: Some browsers default to `all` when nothing is specified some fail. Either way, all is much less performant than picking individual properties to transition. So it's really a best practice to include that as part of the shorthand `transition` attributes.